# PyQt connect() NameError

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

I'm learning how to use PyQt correctly.

Trying to make a window Class with a button that prints a line.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window:
    def __init__(self, args):
        #initializes PyQt
        self.app = QApplication(args)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Example")

        #create label
        self.textLabel = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.textLabel.setText("Hello World!")
        self.textLabel.move(110,85)

        #create button
        self.button = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.button.setText("Click me!")
        self.button.move(64,32)
        #connect button to a method
        self.button.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)

        #set starting position on monitor (50, 50) and window size (320, 200)
        self.widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)

        #show window
        self.widget.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
    def buttonClicked(self):
        print("Button clicked!")

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
    app = Window(sys.argv)
```

When I run the code I get, `NameError: name 'buttonClicked' is not defined`

Double checking all indentation and object syntax it's not apparent to me what is wrong. What's weirder is that such syntax works completely fine when outside of a class.

E.g the following code returns no NameError,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()
   
   button1 = QPushButton(widget)
   button1.setText("Button1")
   button1.move(64,32)
   button1.clicked.connect(button1_clicked)

   button2 = QPushButton(widget)
   button2.setText("Button2")
   button2.move(64,64)
   button2.clicked.connect(button2_clicked)

   widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
   widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Button Click Example")
   widget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())


def button1_clicked():
   print("Button 1 clicked")

def button2_clicked():
   print("Button 2 clicked")   
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Comment: Change to `self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)` and do proper research on instance attributes, methods and the meaning of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't properly referencing the method. when calling `self.button.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)`.

What is required is `self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)`